# How can the ball of radius $\frac{1}{2}$ about $(0,0)$ be open in $[0,1]\times[0,1]$?

Tags: general-topology

First of all - wouldn't that ball contain some points outside of $[0,1]\times[0,1]$?

Second, even if we restricted that ball to $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ , wouldn't there not exist any ball centered at $(0,0)$ contained in this open set?

Comment: You are using the subspace topology so you are only looking at its intersection with the region.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The open sets for the *induced topology on $S$* (from a topological space $\Omega\supseteq S$) are all sets
$$
O\cap S
$$
where $O$ is an open of $\Omega$. That is, in your case, the open sets on $[0,1]\times [0,1]$ are of the form $O\cap([0,1]\times [0,1])$, where $O$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^2$; note that $O\cap([0,1]\times [0,1])$ need not itself be open in $\mathbb{R}^2$.